# Passing a variable before location.reload()

Tags: javascript

I was trying to pass a variable before reload in javascript.
If I used the following code,

```
  var myUrl = location.href;
  if (myUrl.substring(myUrl.length-1) == "#")
  {
  myUrl = myUrl.substring(0, myUrl.length-1);
  }
  myUrl =myUrl+"&abc=Y&bdc=N";
  location.href =myUrl;             
  location.reload();
```

This time I am not getting correct url.ie,I am not getting `&abc=Y&bdc=N` in the URL.  If I put the alert like this,

```
var myUrl = location.href;
if (myUrl.substring(myUrl.length-1) == "#")
{
myUrl = myUrl.substring(0, myUrl.length-1);
}
myUrl =myUrl+"&abc=Y&bdc=N";
location.href =myUrl;
alert(location.href);
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
location.href =myUrl;
location.reload();
```

Use only

```
window.location =myUrl;
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove

```
location.href =myUrl;
location.reload();
```

Use only

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```